# Array.push.setAnyFormatting('red')?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Description:**

Stack Overflow user mhawksey recently did some [fantastic optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289183/long-processing-time-likely-due-to-getvalue-and-cell-inserts) of my code, and in doing so, introduced me to super efficient array pushes. But working with arrays is kind of difficult, because I can't seem to be able to use functions I can when using the traditional .getRange/.setValue approach.

**Problem:**

I need to integrate .setFontColors('red') and .setBackgroundColors('white').

**Code and Images:**

First, I will post the code. Second, an image of what the *currently* code does. Third, an image of what the code *needs* to do.

```
function format() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = s.getLastRow();
  var row;

  //gets a [][] of all values in the column
  var data = s.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  //we are going to build a [][] to output result
  var output = [];

  //loop through all cells in column A
  for (row = 0; row < lastRow; row++) {
    var cellValue = data[row][0];
    var dash = false;
    if (typeof cellValue === 'string') {
      dash = cellValue.substring(0, 1);
    //if a number copy to our output array
    } else {
      output.push([cellValue]);
    }

    //if -dash
    if (dash === "-") {
      //build first + last name
      var name = (data[(row+1)][0]+" "+data[(row+2)][0]).trim();
      //add row for the -state (e.g. -MI)
      output.push([cellValue]);
      output.push([name]);
      output.push(["Order complete"]);
      //add a blank row
      output.push([""]);
      //jump an extra row to speed things up
      row++;
    }
  }
  //set the values we've made in our output [][] array
  s.getRange(1, 1, output.length).setValues(output);
}
```

This is what the code does:

[image: before and after]

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: objective with color]

**Update:**

I've appended a simple, working formatting loop. The problem is, when I run it on a longer column of data, it takes too long to process. From what I understand of the comments, I cannot quickly format a spreadsheet. Am I wrong?

Appended formatting code:

```
//other variables
var range1;

  //loop through column A
  for (var row = 0; row < lastRow; row++) {
    range1 = s.getRange(row + 1, 1);

    //define offsets for if statement
    var offset1 = range1.offset(1, 0);
    var offset2 = range1.offset(2, 0);

    //substring cannot run on numbers, so...
    cellValue = range1.getValue();
    if (typeof cellValue === 'number') {continue;};
    dash = cellValue.substring(0, 1);

    //if -
    if (dash === "-") {
       offset1.setFontColor('red');
       offset2.setBackground('green');
     };
   };
```

Comment: Need more of your code, how is the array getting used? Also not seeing your code it would seem like you can just: data[(row)][0].setFontColor('red'); without the whole redCell and array.push if all your trying to do is set the cell color to red.

Comment: you are trying to apply a spreadsheet range method to a javascript array, this is just like talking in french to a guy from mars...  if he is a gentle guy he won't protest but he won't do anything either.

Comment: Ah ok. So @Sergeinsas, I didn't know how to formulate this question. Is it that I'm incorrectly trying to apply a "range method" to an array? In light of your response, I guess it's best just to write a follow-up loop to format everything. I should have updated code posted within 18 hours from now...

Comment: In the revision 2, the original content of the question was completely replaced by new content. Instead of doing this kind of revisions it's better to post a new question, I think. If you want that the people that answered get a notification, add a comment to their answers.

Comment: Alright @Rubén, sorry for messing this up. While trying to improve the question quality, I screwed it up :/ I didn't realize the cascading effect that would cause.

Comment: No problem, just keep this in mind for your next question that requires to be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use all the various spreadsheet methods to **get** and **set** colors, font sizes, font weights, etc. *to* and *from* distinct arrays but you can not mix these "attributes" in one single item. See [the doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

Or even handier, in your script editor write a script that defines a range and play with the auto complete to see everything you can do with it...

(control+space keys)

[image]

---

### edit following your code update.

You should create a second array that holds all the background colors of your range and fill it according to your needs.
In the code below I build the array in parrallels with your output array, not very elegantly but rather systematically to show how it works.

Note that null value means "no background color" while #0F0 is the hexadecimal code for green but you can also use the 'green' string if you prefer...

```
    ...
    var output = [];
    var backGrounds=[]
    //loop through all cells in column A
    for (row = 0; row < lastRow; row++) {
      var cellValue = data[row][0];
      var dash = false;
      if (typeof cellValue === 'string') {
        dash = cellValue.substring(0, 1);
        //if a number copy to our output array
      } else {
        output.push([cellValue]);
        backGrounds.push([null]);
      }

      //if -dash
      if (dash === "-") {
        //build first + last name
        var name = (data[(row+1)][0]+" "+data[(row+2)][0]).trim();
        //add row for the -state (e.g. -MI)
        output.push([cellValue]);
        backGrounds.push([null]);
        output.push([name]);
        backGrounds.push([null]);
        output.push(["Order complete"]);
        backGrounds.push(['#0F0']);
        //add a blank row
        output.push([""]);
        backGrounds.push([null]);
        //jump an extra row to speed things up
        row++;
      }
    }
  s.getRange(1, 1, output.length).setBackgrounds(backGrounds);
...
```

Comment: This systematic approach helped me clearly understand it, and it works perfectly on long data columns. You can scale this up by simply adding a additional arrays right below each of the backGrounds statements. i.e. var fontColors=[ ]. Hitting control-space is also super helpful for novices like myself, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

REMARK: The OP did a huge change from [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35431531/1) to revision 3. Following is the content taken from the source of the revision 1.

---

> Is it possible to push text to a spreadsheet **with formatting** such
>   as .setFontColor, .setBackgroundColor or .setBorder? I've been
>   monkeying around with  code but never get an error message. It just
>   doesn't do anything. I'm working with something like this:
>
> ```js
>     if (cell === "This should be red") {
>     var redCell = (data[(row)][0]).setFontColor('red');
>     array.push([redCell]);
>     }
> ```

---

Following is my answer to the revision 1.

To copy the value and format from one cell or range to another use [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination).

From the above link

```
 // The code below will copy the first 5 columns over to the 6th column.
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), 5);
 rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 6));
 }
```

Comment: I'm sorry @Ruben, I didn't consider that my huge revision would make your answer look inconsistent, and wasted your time in having to come back and edit your answer. Moreover, this isn't the first time you've helped me out. Humble apologies :|