# How to speed google apps script execution time

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, gmail-api

This script processes 3 CSV files from GMAIL threads, the execution time was fast until I added the regex portion searching the body for

```
tmp = truncatedContent.match(/Date Tripped:\s*([:\w\s]+)\r?\n/);
tmp = truncatedContent.match(/Business Date:\s([\w\s]+\(\w+\))/);
```

With the addition of this portion, the script completes successfully but now takes approximately 17 seconds to complete as opposed to 4 seconds before.

I assume there's an innefficiency in here, seeking guidance:

```
function SLSalesImportFromGmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // Get the spreadsheet file once

  //gets first(latest) message with set label
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('South Loop').getThreads(0,1);
  if (threads && threads.length > 0) {
    var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
    // Get the first email message of a threads
    var content = message.getPlainBody();
    var tmp,
    truncatedContent = content.match(/^([^\r\n]+\r?\n){5}/)[0];
    // Get the plain text body of the email message
    // You may also use getRawContent() for parsing HTML
    // Implement Parsing rules using regular expressions
    if (truncatedContent) {

      tmp = truncatedContent.match(/Date Tripped:\s*([:\w\s]+)\r?\n/);
      var tripped = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'N/A';

      tmp = truncatedContent.match(/Business Date:\s([\w\s]+\(\w+\))/);
      var businessdate = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'N/A';
    // Get all of the attachments and loop through them.
    var attachments = message.getAttachments(); 
    for (var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
      var attachment = attachments[i];
      var title = attachment.getName();

      // Is the attachment a CSV file
      attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
      var table = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString());
      if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
        switch (title) { // Update the specified sheets
          case "Sales.csv":
            /**
            * Clears the sheet of values & formatting and inserts the new table 
            * using the Apps Script built-in CSV parser.
            * @param {string} sheetName - The name of the sheet to update
            * @returns {undefined}
            */
            ss.getSheetByName("South Loop Sales").getRange("A:M").clear();
            ss.getSheetByName("South Loop Sales").getRange(1, 1, table.length, table[0].length).setValues(table);
            ss.getSheetByName("South Loop Sales").appendRow(['Last Sync:', tripped]);
            ss.getSheetByName("South Loop Sales").appendRow(['POS Date:', businessdate]);
            break;
          case "Labor.csv":
            ss.getSheetByName("South Loop Labor").getRange("A:M").clear();
            ss.getSheetByName("South Loop Labor").getRange(1, 1, table.length, table[0].length).setValues(table);
            break;
          case "ServerPerformance.csv":
            ss.getSheetByName("South Loop Servers").getRange("A:M").clear();
            ss.getSheetByName("South Loop Servers").getRange(1, 1, table.length, table[0].length).setValues(table);            
            break;
        }
      }      
    }
    if( message.getSubject().indexOf('END OF DAY') !== -1) {
    SLlogTodaysSales();
    SLlogTodaysServers();
    }
    if( message.getSubject().indexOf('END OF WEEK') !== -1) {
    SLlogTodaysSales();
    SLlogTodaysServers();
    SLlogWeeksLabor();
    }
    }
    //marks the Gmail message as read, unstars it and deletes it using Gmail API (Filter sets a star)
  message.markRead();
  message.unstar();
  Gmail.Users.Messages.remove("me", message.getId()); // Added
  }
}

function SLlogTodaysSales() {
  var todaysSales = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('South Loop Sales Log!SLSalesImport');
  var logSheet = todaysSales.getSheet();
  logSheet.appendRow(
    todaysSales.getValues()
    .reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b); }) // flatten the 2D array to 1D
  );
}
function SLlogWeeksLabor() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('South Loop Labor Log');
  var rg=sh.getRange('SLLaborImport');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
function SLlogTodaysServers() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('South Loop Server Log');
  var rg=sh.getRange('SLServerReport');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```

Execution Transcript, looks like it's getting stuck on appendRow for some reason.:

```
[20-02-20 13:37:31:218 CST] SpreadsheetApp.getActive() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:31:420 CST] GmailApp.getUserLabelByName([Sundance Square]) [0.2 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:31:569 CST] GmailApp.GmailLabel.getThreads([0, 1]) [0.149 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:31:712 CST] GmailApp.GmailThread.getMessages() [0.141 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:31:952 CST] GmailApp.GmailMessage.getPlainBody() [0.24 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:31:958 CST] GmailApp.GmailMessage.getAttachments() [0.002 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:31:958 CST] GmailApp.GmailAttachment.getName() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:31:959 CST] GmailApp.GmailAttachment.setContentTypeFromExtension() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:32:122 CST] GmailApp.GmailAttachment.getDataAsString() [0.163 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:32:123 CST] Utilities.parseCsv([Sales

Order Status:,"All"
Report By:,"User closed"
Date Range:,"Current day (20 Feb 2020)"
Time Range:,"All day"

Void Totals
Amount,Quantity
12.0000,4

Financial Summary
Summary,Net Sal...) [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:32:123 CST] GmailApp.GmailAttachment.getContentType() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:32:270 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Sundance Square Sales]) [0.146 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:32:271 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([A:M]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:32:272 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.clear() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:32:272 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Sundance Square Sales]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:32:273 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([1, 1, 106, 8]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:32:281 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues([[[Sales, , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , ], [Order Status:, All, , , , , , ], [Report By:, User closed, , , , , , ], [Date Range:, Current day (20 Feb 2020), , , , , , ], [Time Range:, All day, , , , ,...) [0.007 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:32:282 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Sundance Square Sales]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:41:723 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.appendRow([[Last Sync:, 20 Feb 2020 1:36 PM]]) [9.44 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:41:868 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Sundance Square Sales]) [0.144 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:43:457 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.appendRow([[POS Date:, 20 Feb 2020 (Open)]]) [1.588 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:43:457 CST] GmailApp.GmailAttachment.getName() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:43:458 CST] GmailApp.GmailAttachment.setContentTypeFromExtension() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:43:624 CST] GmailApp.GmailAttachment.getDataAsString() [0.165 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:43:624 CST] Utilities.parseCsv([Labor

Date Range:,"Current week (17 Feb 2020 to 23 Feb 2020)"
Time Range:,"All day"

User Shifts
User,Job,Date In,Date Out,Reg Hrs,Rate,Reg Amt,OT Hrs,OT Rate,OT Amt,Total
Hazel Castillo,03-K...) [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:43:625 CST] GmailApp.GmailAttachment.getContentType() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:43:716 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Sundance Square Labor]) [0.09 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:43:716 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([A:M]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:43:717 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.clear() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:43:718 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Sundance Square Labor]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:43:718 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([1, 1, 71, 11]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:43:725 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues([[[Labor, , , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , , ], [Date Range:, Current week (17 Feb 2020 to 23 Feb 2020), , , , , , , , , ], [Time Range:, All day, , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , , ], [Us...) [0.006 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:43:726 CST] GmailApp.GmailAttachment.getName() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:43:727 CST] GmailApp.GmailAttachment.setContentTypeFromExtension() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:44:037 CST] GmailApp.GmailAttachment.getDataAsString() [0.31 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:44:037 CST] Utilities.parseCsv([ServerPerformance

Order Status:,"All"
Report By:,"User closed"
Service Types:,"Table Service"
Date Range:,"Current day (20 Feb 2020)"
Time Range:,"All day"

Sales by User, Cost Center, Segme...) [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:44:038 CST] GmailApp.GmailAttachment.getContentType() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:44:038 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Sundance Square Servers]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:44:039 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([A:M]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:44:039 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.clear() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:44:039 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Sundance Square Servers]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:44:040 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange([1, 1, 36, 13]) [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:44:044 CST] SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues([[[ServerPerformance, , , , , , , , , , , , ], [, , , , , , , , , , , , ], [Order Status:, All, , , , , , , , , , , ], [Report By:, User closed, , , , , , , , , , , ], [Service Types:, Table Service, ...) [0.003 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:44:044 CST] GmailApp.GmailMessage.getSubject() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:44:044 CST] GmailApp.GmailMessage.getSubject() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:44:380 CST] GmailApp.GmailMessage.markRead() [0.336 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:44:695 CST] GmailApp.GmailMessage.unstar() [0.314 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:44:697 CST] GmailApp.GmailMessage.getId() [0 seconds]
[20-02-20 13:37:48:477 CST] Execution succeeded [13.821 seconds total runtime]
```

Comment: Show view>execution transcript

Comment: @TheMaster I'm not seeing that option inside google apps script, running V8.

Comment: @TheMaster When i try to view logs, it gets stuck on "Waiting for logs, please wait..."

Comment: Switch back to rhino and show execution  transcript

Comment: Got it, editing results into main post.  Does appendRow take longer because it's searching for the last row?  If so, maybe if i have static cells assigned on the sheet for this info instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google app script timeout ~ 5 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450819/google-app-script-timeout-5-minutes)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289183/

Comment: Sorry I clicked out of that on accident, but yes seems like it may be related.

Comment: What did you click out of? Avoid appendRow. Use setValues(). Reduce interactions between script and sheet(to preferably to 1 or 2).

Comment: Awesome, could you help me with the proper execution for that?
Preferably setValues tripped C1, setValues businessdate F1.
Must be done after the sheet is cleared and the CSV is imported of course.

Comment: Sure. Let me know  what trouble you're having

Comment: appendRow was definitely the issue, changing to setValue has made the script run 75% faster.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Switch from .appendRow to .getRange/.setValue.
Change:

```
            ss.getSheetByName("South Loop Sales").appendRow(['Last Sync:', tripped]);
            ss.getSheetByName("South Loop Sales").appendRow(['POS Date:', businessdate]);
```

to:

```
            ss.getSheetByName("South Loop Sales").getRange("C2").setValue(tripped);
            ss.getSheetByName("South Loop Sales").getRange("C1").setValue(businessdate);
```