# Google script stops after 5mins of execution

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running this code and the code needs to be run for a very long period of time, but google script shows an error "exceeds maximum execution time". I read somewhere that using triggers this can be implemented where the script turns off and resumes where it left. But I am not able to do so. How to make it resume where it left??

```
function myFunction() {

  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var sheet = app.getSheets()[2];

  sheet.getRange(1, 1).setBackground('green');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for(var x=0; x<data.length; x++){


    if(data[x][1] == 1) {


        var name1 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(4)).getValue();

        var comp1 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(8)).setValue(name1);

    }
    else if(data[x][1] == 2){
      var name2 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(4)).getValue();
      var comp2 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(9)).setValue(name2);}
    else if(data[x][1] == 3){
      var name3 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(4)).getValue();
      var comp3 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(10)).setValue(name3);}
    else if(data[x][1] == 4){
      var name4 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(4)).getValue();
      var comp4 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(11)).setValue(name4);}
      else if(data[x][1] != 4 && data[x][1] != 3 && data[x][1] != 2 && data[x][1] != 1){
        comp1 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(8)).setValue(name1);
        comp2 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(9)).setValue(name2);
        comp3 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(10)).setValue(name3);
        comp4 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(11)).setValue(name4);
      }

var word = sheet.getRange((x+1),(3)).getValue();
var nextword = sheet.getRange((x+2),(3)).getValue();
comp1 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(8)).setValue(name1);
comp2 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(9)).setValue(name2);
comp3 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(10)).setValue(name3);
comp4 = sheet.getRange((x+1),(11)).setValue(name4);    

    if(word != nextword){
      name1 = "";
      name2 = "";
      name3 = "";
      name4 = "";
    }    

}
}
```

Comment: You need to remove all those `getValue` and `setValue` calls. `sheet.getRange((x+1),(4)).getValue()` is basically `data[x][3]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google app script timeout ~ 5 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450819/google-app-script-timeout-5-minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage triggers [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) using [Script Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script), for what you're trying to do, this will involve checking the runtime regularly using something like:

`taskStartTime = new Date();`

at the beginning of the script and preiodically checking how long the script has been running with something like:

`endTime = new Date();
 duration = Math.round((endTime.getTime() - taskStartTime.getTime())/1000);
 tasks_Processed_Array[tasks_Processed_Array.length - 1].duration = duration;`

And if the duration is close to the max, then create a trigger for later and start where you left off.

However, there's no need to do this for your script. You are overusing `.getValue()` and `.setValue()` and this is slowing down the script significantly. Instead use `getValues()` to gather all data from a sheet at once, and then manipulate it in the script. Use `setValues()` to paste all the values at once. [This post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/49132/how-can-i-speed-up-my-google-spreadsheet-script) explains it more.

Every time you use `getValue()` the script needs to wait for Google to respond. It can be frustrating working with the Arrays that `getValues()` returns, but used correctly it will take a fraction of the execution time.

Here are a few examples:
`var name1 = data[x][3]
 var name2 = data[x][4]`

Better yet, define `name` once before the if statement.

The setValues part is a little more challenging. Define an array outside the loop `var ary = []` and then add elements to the array using `ary.push([colToPasteIn, name])` that way you have a reference for where it should be pasted.

But getValue() slows down the script much more than setValue() so I think fixing the first part will be sufficient. More explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289183/long-processing-time-likely-due-to-getvalue-and-cell-inserts).

Comment: The process is going on in a loop, it checks few cells of each row and append other cells of the same row, so I don't think it is possible to set values at once. 
and how do I save the row number before I break, so that I can resume from the same row?

Comment: You certainly can, see the revised answer. Going the triggers route might seem simpler, but it will result in a much more complicated solution that will take exponentially more time to execute... but you can save the row variable in a cell in the spreadsheet....

Comment: Thanks, just fixing the get value did it for me, I didn't need to form an array or something. It is now processing 10k+ rows in 3 mins or so, just by eliminating get value.