# Speeding up an onEdit() function in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

We're managing all changes from multiple sheets (one for each of 29 different locations) to be reflected in one main_db. The main_db is then hooked up to Data Studio for Analytics.

We have implemented a "updates_to_db" record sheet for the changes being made, and then running a triggered service every 10 mins that does the actual getting and setting of data in the main_db.

I faced issues with onEdit() functions writing data over each other when getLastRow() was returning the same value for onEdit()'s that were fired off in quick succession. I've implemented a PropertyKey to now hold this value. onEdit() first updates this value, and then continues. This way all subsequent onEdits() are correctly being written to the updated lastRow.

**onOpen() function**
This sets the PropertyKey value for real last row in the updates records sheet accurately.

```
function onOpen() {
  
  // Welcome message
  var message = 'The current time is ' + new Date().toString();
  var title = 'Welcome to xxxxxx DASHBOARD';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(message, title);

  var last_row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(push_to_db_sheet).getLastRow();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('last_row_updates_sheet', last_row + 1);

}
```

**onEdit() function**

```
function onEdit(e){

  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var date_stamp = new Date();
  var tabs = ["Customer Requests","Indent Status","Tracking Acknowledgements","Actual Costs","Balance Payments","Payment Updates"];
  
  if(tabs.indexOf(activeSheet.getName()) !== -1){

    var row_to_edit = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('last_row_updates_sheet');
    row_to_edit= +row_to_edit; // converting string to int
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('last_row_updates_sheet', row_to_edit + 1);

    var cell = e.range;
    var col = cell.getColumn();
    var changes_sheet = e.source.getSheetByName(push_to_db_sheet);
  //  var last_row = changes_sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    
    changes_sheet.getRange(row_to_edit, 1).setValue(date_stamp);
    changes_sheet.getRange(row_to_edit, 2).setValue(activeSheet.getName());
    changes_sheet.getRange(row_to_edit, 3).setValue(activeSheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),3,1,1).getValue());
    changes_sheet.getRange(row_to_edit, 4).setValue(cell.getColumn())
    changes_sheet.getRange(row_to_edit, 5).setValue(e.value);
      
    cell.setNote('Last modified: ' + date_stamp); // helps the user know when the last edit was made
    cell.setBackground("#FBF7EC"); // helps the user visually see when the update has been captured. I can move this up to make it "seem" faster...
  } // IF tab name matches

}
```

Any ideas on how I can speed up onEdit()? It is currently taking between 4 - 13 seconds to run. Eventually, I will be calling email and SMS trigger functions based on specific cells which were edited. I'd like a pop-up with the email/sms to be shown, and then a confirmation button will trigger the email/sms.

I'm worried that with a long onEdit() time the user will be several columns ahead when the email/sms pop-up dialogue is displayed.

Comment: Is there any reason I shouldn't close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/29800759/ or https://stackoverflow.com/a/57836700?

Comment: @TheMaster thank you for the reference links. Once I am done with the entire function improvements, including email/sms dialogue triggers, I'll come back here and post my improvement methods that actually worked, with some performance results.

Comment: I'm closing it. If you'd like to add  generalised answers, You can add it to any of the duplicate questions linked above, So that there will be a single thread of data instead of split up data. Alternatively, If you'd like a specific answer, you can edit your existing answer. Also read up on DRY principle. Avoid repeating entire global calls: `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()` and `activeSheet.getName()` .. preferably store them in a variable.

Comment: Ok - got it! This was my first Q on the site, thanks for showing me the ropes! Will keep this in mind next time @TheMaster

Answer (score 1):

I've updated this list of read/writes:

```
changes_sheet.getRange(row_to_edit, 1).setValue(date_stamp);
    changes_sheet.getRange(row_to_edit, 2).setValue(activeSheet.getName());
    changes_sheet.getRange(row_to_edit, 3).setValue(activeSheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),3,1,1).getValue());
    changes_sheet.getRange(row_to_edit, 4).setValue(cell.getColumn())
    changes_sheet.getRange(row_to_edit, 5).setValue(e.value);
```

To this:

```
    changes_sheet.getRange(row_to_edit, 1, 1, 5).setValues([[date_stamp , activeSheet.getName() , activeSheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),3,1,1).getValue() , cell.getColumn() , e.value]]);
```

Notes:

- setValues() needs a 2D array. Make sure to wrap the data in the appropriate [] brackets to achieve this when setting data like I am.
- The previous method had an average onEdit completion time of **7.6988 s**
- The updated method has an average onEdit completion time of **3.6741 s** -> 52% decrease

Is this a reasonable execution time to expect for an onEdit() function?