# Compare two json array and update dataSheet with setValues updating empty rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a datasheet that contains the ordered data. The sheet consists of thousands of rows identified by the order id.
In the second column I have all the data grouped as json string. The new values are added starting from the last row.

**This operation works.**

My problem starts when I have to update the changes of some values of ids.

The source where I parse data, both for append and update is a json api.

This is my simulation dataSheet:

Start dataSheet[image]

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | string | shipped | timestamp | id | countitems | destination | delivery |
| 2 | {"id":"x11","shipped":null,"countItems":"21","destination":"Paris","delivery":null} |  |  | x11 | 21 | Paris |  |
| 3 | {"id":"x167","shipped":null,"countItems":"3","destination":"Lyon","delivery":null} |  |  | x167 | 3 | Lyon |  |
| 4 | {"id":"x89","shipped":null,"countItems":"8","destination":"Berlin","delivery":null} |  |  | x89 | 8 | Berlin |  |
| 5 | {"id":"x9811","shipped":null,"countItems":"2","destination":"Madrid","delivery":null} |  |  | x9811 | 2 | Madrid |  |
| 6 | {"id":"x73","shipped":null,"countItems":"9","destination":"Liverpool","delivery":null} |  |  | x73 | 9 | Liverpool |  |

This is my current procedure:

*1) Apply a filter to the json source, selecting the elements where "shipped" is yes.*

```
// My API is for business use, so I can't share URL and token.
// Request and download work perfectly

const loadShipped = () => {return jsonApi().filter(k=>k.shipped == "yes")}
```

**I get this output**

```
var shipped = [
 {"id":"x167","shipped":"yes","countItems":"3","destination":"Lyon","delivery":"22/09/2023"}
,{"id":"x9811","shipped":"yes","countItems":"2","destination":"Madrid","delivery":"27/09/2023"}
]
```

*2) Create a json output of column B and apply a filter selecting the elements where "shipped" is null.*

```
const jsDataSheet = () => {
  const colJS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("B5:B")
                              .getDisplayValues().filter(col=>col[0]);
  const data = `[${colJS.filter(o=>o!='').join(',')}]`;
  const dataSheetJson = [...new Set(JSON.parse(data))];
  return dataSheetJson.filter(k=>!k.shipped)
}
```

**I get this output**

```
var toUpdate = [
 {"id":"x167","shipped":null,"countItems":"3","destination":"Lyon","delivery":null}
,{"id":"x9811","shipped":null,"countItems":"2","destination":"Madrid","delivery":null}
]
```

*cons*: The columns are not adjacent and usually the two json have different length and sort.

This is the script I'm using, is very slow, this is the problem for me, I have too much data to update and many cells to fill. For this situation I have reduced the number of elements.

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    for(var i=0;i<toUpdate.length;i++){
      for(var j=0;j<shipped.length;j++){
        if(toUpdate[i].id == shipped[j].id){

          const time = Date.parse(new Date()) / 1000;
          const ship = shipped[j].shipped;
          const dDel = shipped[j].delivery;

          const newJS = 
          JSON.stringify({...toUpdate[i]
          ,timestamp:time
          ,shipped:ship
          ,delivery:dDel
          });

          sheet.getRange(i + 5,2).setValue(newJS)
          sheet.getRange(i + 5,3).setValue(ship)
          sheet.getRange(i + 5,4).setValue(time)          
          sheet.getRange(i + 5,8).setValue(dDel)
        }
      }
    }
```

**This is final result**

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXUh7.png)

| string | shipped | timestamp | id | countItems | destination | delivery |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"id":"x11","shipped":null,"countItems":"21","destination":"Paris","delivery":null} |  |  | x11 | 21 | Paris |  |
| {"id":"x167","shipped":null,"countItems":"3","destination":"Lyon","delivery":null} | yes |  | x167 | 3 | Lyon | 22/09/2023 |
| {"id":"x89","shipped":null,"countItems":"8","destination":"Berlin","delivery":null} |  |  | x89 | 8 | Berlin |  |
| {"id":"x9811","shipped":null,"countItems":"2","destination":"Madrid","delivery":null} | yes |  | x9811 | 2 | Madrid | 27/09/2023 |
| {"id":"x73","shipped":null,"countItems":"9","destination":"Liverpool","delivery":null} |  |  | x73 | 9 | Liverpool |  |

The **target** is to update data once, update string rows and put the values into empty cells, without changing values already added.

[shared google link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B01S14RTlSqfoNsxRqI08HZ2plIipxi8bLkQeq3zg5c/)

Comment: Create a output array first and then setValues in a batch.

Comment: I cannot understand how my question can be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289183/long-processing-time-likely-due-to-getvalue-and-cell-insert. Do I need to comment in that question?

Comment: You're using `sheet.getRange` and `setValue` multiple times and inside a loop. That's why it `is very slow`

Comment: Yes, you right, this is the reason that I have to use setValues but is a double loop and if use setValues I have [0,1,2,3] as index, while I have to skip rows that should not be update

Comment: You get all the data in the sheet first. Modify what is necessary and throw all the data back to the sheet.

Comment: I would need a copiable data table to be able provide you with a working solution.

Comment: Shared link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B01S14RTlSqfoNsxRqI08HZ2plIipxi8bLkQeq3zg5c/ as editor

Comment: I don't following links to spreadsheets.

Comment: I don't know what you follow, I have added in my question two tables.

Comment: @TheMaster I'm trying with jsDataSheet().map((o,i)=>shipped.filter(r=>r.id == o.id)
  .map(m=>[i + 1,JSON.stringify(m),m.shipped,Date.parse(new Date()) / 1000,m.delivery])) to have data filtered

Comment: If you isolate the column with the id into a single flat array from your starting sheet and keeping all of the data in the array.  Then that Array.indexOf(id from api) will give you the index into the array that you should be updating.  Update all of those rows and use setValues again to reload the spreadsheet.

Comment: I wouldn't mind doing this but I really don't wish to share my email address and following the link to the spreadsheet does that.  And now SO will not allow us to have more than one login which really sucks.

Comment: First, did you mean column A for json output? As that is how it is in the picture. `and I can not recreate the entire array,` Why not? What's the problem with replacing same values with same values again?

Comment: I mean column B of the screenshot, in my question there is also the function to create the json. My datasheet consists of more than 20 columns. I have to keep track of the products that are ordered and update when shipped, but if for example the discount for shipping is changed, I lose the old value

Comment: @hub2sell I'm still not getting it. `for example the discount for shipping is changed, I lose the old value`. So what is the expected value? Keep  the old discount or the new discount?  Say, Discount  is 15% and is in G15. New data from json comes in and if it includes 20% discount, we update it in the sheet. Else, we overwrite the 15% by the existing 15% - nothing changed. Both are possible. But in case of `setValues` we overwrite with either the old or the new, but  there is no unintended data loss.

Comment: Column B (json output) must be updated by adding if shipped and the date of shipment and delivery. Using the setvalue I add only these elements in the json, the content of the rows I analyze it from the api and if something has changed, put new data in the row, then when I need I check the differences between column B and rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
const shipped /*data from api*/ = [
  {
    id: 'x167',
    shipped: 'yes',
    countItems: '3',
    destination: 'Lyon',
    delivery: '22/09/2023',
  },
  {
    id: 'x9811',
    shipped: 'yes',
    countItems: '2',
    destination: 'Madrid',
    delivery: '27/09/2023',
  },
];
const sheet =
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('[DATA SHEET]'),
  dataRange = sheet.getDataRange(),
  data = dataRange.getDisplayValues(),
  idColIdx = 5 - 1,
  idJsonIdx = 2 - 1,
  shippedMap = shipped.reduce((m, c) => m.set(c.id, c), new Map());

data.forEach((row) => {
  const idx = row[idColIdx];
  if (shippedMap.has(idx)) {
    const thisShipped = shippedMap.get(idx),
      time = Date.parse(new Date()) / 1000,
      ship = thisShipped.shipped,
      del = thisShipped.delivery,
      thisUpdate = [
        JSON.stringify({
          ...JSON.parse(row[idJsonIdx]),
          timestamp: time,
          shipped: ship,
          delivery: del,
        }),
        ship,
        time,
        del,
      ];
    [2, 3, 6, 8].map((c) => c - 1).forEach((c, k) => (row[c] = thisUpdate[k]));
  }
});
dataRange.setValues(data);
```

#### Mock Test:

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const shipped /*data from api*/ = [
  {
    id: 'x167',
    shipped: 'yes',
    countItems: '3',
    destination: 'Lyon',
    delivery: '22/09/2023',
  },
  {
    id: 'x9811',
    shipped: 'yes',
    countItems: '2',
    destination: 'Madrid',
    delivery: '27/09/2023',
  },
];
const data = [
    [
      '2',
      '{"id":"x167","shipped":null,"countItems":"3","destination":"Lyon","delivery":null}',
      '',
      '',
      'x167',
      '3',
      'Lyon',
    ],

    [
      '3',
      '{"id":"x89","shipped":null,"countItems":"8","destination":"Berlin","delivery":null}',
      '',
      '',
      'x89',
      '8',
      'Berlin',
    ],

    [
      '4',
      '{"id":"x9811","shipped":null,"countItems":"2","destination":"Madrid","delivery":null}',
      '',
      '',
      'x9811',
      '2',
      'Madrid',
    ],

    [
      '5',
      '{"id":"x73","shipped":null,"countItems":"9","destination":"Liverpool","delivery":null}',
      '',
      '',
      'x73',
      '9',
      'Liverpool',
    ],
  ],
  idColIdx = 5 - 1,
  idJsonIdx = 2 - 1,
  shippedMap = shipped.reduce((m, c) => m.set(c.id, c), new Map());

data.forEach((row) => {
  const json = JSON.parse(row[idJsonIdx])
  const idx = json.id;
  if (shippedMap.has(idx)) {
    const thisShipped = shippedMap.get(idx),
      time = Date.parse(new Date()) / 1000,
      ship = thisShipped.shipped,
      del = thisShipped.delivery,
      thisUpdate = [
        JSON.stringify({
          ...json,
          timestamp: time,
          shipped: ship,
          delivery: del,
        }),
        ship,
        time,
        del,
      ];
    [2, 3, 6, 8].map((c) => c - 1).forEach((c, k) => (row[c] = thisUpdate[k]));
  }
});
console.log(data);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your script works but I say this: 
In my question I asked to do the check between column B (json output by my function) and the API, your script does a check between the sheet and the API, I can also accept it if there are no alternatives. For me is important to check the rows that do not contain "yes" in the shipped column. I changed the range and added 'if (shippedMap.has(idx) && row[2] !== "yes")' , is this correct? If you confirm the first and second, we can define resolved

Comment: @hub2sell Yes.  Also, It's not hard to modify to use column B. I modified the mock test code to show you how.

Comment: Ok, I realized that my function `const jsDataSheet = () => {
  const colJS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("B5:B")
                              .getDisplayValues().filter(col=>col[0]);
  const data = `[${colJS.filter(o=>o!='').join(',')}]`;
  const dataSheetJson = [...new Set(JSON.parse(data))];
  return dataSheetJson.filter(k=>!k.shipped)
}`
that gets data from column B and converts to json is to be discarded, right?

Comment: problem, from my api, line `if (shipped.has(idx))` I get this error `TypeError: shipped.has is not a function`. I'm just using my api url

Comment: I create a Shipped [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Only `Map` has method `.has`

Comment: I honestly don't understand, my api returns a json array like the array in my question but with many more keys / elements

Comment: This line `shippedMap = shipped.reduce((m, c) => m.set(c.id, c), new Map());` creates a `Map` from `Array`. `Map` isn't easily visible in the logs. You can use the debugger to examine it(if needed).

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't fix it, I keep getting the same error `shipped.has is not a function`,it means that reduce doesn't even work?

Comment: Show your `.reduce` line. If you're frustrated, Take a break...Come back after a few hours and look into the code again.. you'll figure it out.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I didn't respect commas, I had created the `var toInsert` without closing it with `;` . I don't know if it's a coincidence but now it works. If it's a coincidence then I take a break of a few days

Comment: Coincidence or not, it works and I thank you for your time, you saved me from a nervous breakdown ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you isolate the column with the id into a single flat array from your starting sheet and keeping all of the data in the array. Then that Array.indexOf(id from api) will give you the index into the array that you should be updating. Update all of those rows and use setValues again to reload the spreadsheet.

```
function myfunk() {
  const shipped = [{ "id": "x167", "shipped": "yes", "countItems": "3", "destination": "Lyon", "delivery": "22/09/2023" }, { "id": "x9811", "shipped": "yes", "countItems": "2", "destination": "Madrid", "delivery": "27/09/2023" }];
  const sr = 2;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//change sheet name and data start row
  let vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const idA = vs.map((r, i) => r[3]);
  shipped.forEach((r, i) => {
    vs[idA.indexOf(shipped[i].id)] = [JSON.stringify(shipped[i]), "yes", new Date().valueOf(), shipped[i].id, shipped[i].countItems, shipped[i].destination, shipped[i].delivery];
  });
  sh.getRange(sr, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```

My output:

| Row\Col | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | string | shipped | timestamp | id | countitems | destination | delivery |
| 2 | {"id":"x11","shipped":null,"countItems":"21","destination":"Paris","delivery":null} |  |  | x11 | 21 | Paris |  |
| 3 | {"id":"x167","shipped":"yes","countItems":"3","destination":"Lyon","delivery":"22/09/2023"} | yes | 1694983369773 | x167 | 3 | Lyon | 22/09/2023 |
| 4 | {"id":"x89","shipped":null,"countItems":"8","destination":"Berlin","delivery":null} |  |  | x89 | 8 | Berlin |  |
| 5 | {"id":"x9811","shipped":"yes","countItems":"2","destination":"Madrid","delivery":"27/09/2023"} | yes | 1694983369773 | x9811 | 2 | Madrid | 27/09/2023 |
| 6 | {"id":"x73","shipped":null,"countItems":"9","destination":"Liverpool","delivery":null} |  |  | x73 | 9 | Liverpool |  |

Comment: I'm trying the code, it works but I have two questions, I have to compare the string column converted to json and the api, is it useless in my situation? Another question, your script replaces values, I need to update the empty cells, so how skip columns with a single operation?

Comment: Added const idA = vs.filter(r=>r[1]!="yes").map((r,i) => r[3])

Comment: I didn't filter like that because that will mess up the setValues() array and some of the old data may be overwritten.  I'd keep all of the  data so that when you rewrite the data with setValues() all of the old data will remain intact

Comment: Thank you for your time but I have to check the items that have not been shipped, I have thousands of rows, I can't check the same rows so I have to apply a filter somewhere. Unfortunately data should not be overwritten and your script overwrites old values. I'm unable to fix your script

Comment: My script worked on the sample data but will not work with your modifications.

Comment: I understand but I d'like to solve this problem. I create the json from the column also to have the old values and compare them with the new ones, if they were to be different.What do you recommend? In my question I had expressed the intention not to replace the data already stored and that I had many elements

Comment: I don't understand what you have to do with the other rows please explain

Comment: It seems to me that you are now changing the question.  I'm no longer interested in investing any more time into this question.  If you wanted something different than what you asked for you should have made that clear in your question.  I'm done.

Comment: In my question :
The target is to update data once, update string rows and put the values into empty cells, without changing values already added.
I have to filter elelments not shipped, not all elements, maybe my English is not clear and I apologize for it but from my question
2) Create a json output of column B and apply a filter selecting the elements where "shipped" is null.