# Why is the optimized g script code slower than the "inefficient" one?

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

One spreadsheet have a 50x36 array with values. The function should get values from certain columns and build an array if col+1 cell is greater than 0. The first part of the code is calling the page once, getting all the values in one line, then with nested for and an if, creating the desired array.
The second part is doing the exact same thing, but calling the page with getValues() several times, which supposed to be slower and not a good practice according to google. The fist one spits out a result 100ms slower than the second one. Can someone explain?

```
function PieseArray() {
  
  let pag = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Configuracion');

//start counting time for the first part
  let start1 = new Date
  let allTheParts = pag.getRange(11,40,50,36).getValues()
  let array2=[]
  for (let i=0;i<36;i=i+4){
    for (let j=0;j<allTheParts.length;j++){
      if(allTheParts[j][i+1]>0){
        array2.push([allTheParts[j][i],allTheParts[j][i+1]])
      }
    }
  }
  let end1 = new Date
  Logger.log(end1-start1)
  
//start of the second part 
let start2 = new Date
let piese = []
for(let k=40;k<=72;k=k+4){
  piese = piese.concat(pag.getRange(11,k,50,2).getValues())
}
  let array1=[]
  for (let i=0;i<piese.length;i++){
    if(piese[i][1]!=''){
      array1.push(piese[i])
    }
  }
  let end2 = new Date
  Logger.log(end2-start2)

  return(array1)
}
```

Execution log

```
1:06:11 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:06:12 PM  Info    107.0 (first part)
1:06:12 PM  Info    15.0 (second part)
1:06:12 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

The result is the same array, but the execution time is very strange. I was expecting that the second part of the code to be way slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps script has [lookahead caching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57836700), where the values you need are already cached. If you run the code one after another, getting the same values from the same range, then the values cached from the first code is used in  the second.

Furthermore, Both the codes are not doing the same thing. The main comparison is different.

> if(allTheParts[j][i+1]>0){

is different from

> if(piese[i][1]!=''){

To properly time these functions,

- Use two different functions - calling them one after another shuffling each time. Make sure the execution of each is completely stopped before the next function is called.
- Use built in `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` to correctly time the functions
- Make sure both the code does the same number and type of operations. Not just that the output is the same.
- Run each test thrice or more.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I was actually reading about "Lookahead" thing that google has, and actually thought to separate the things, yet I didn't. I don't need to shuffle the functions as just by testing separately there is an average of 50+ ms in favor of the optimal script as expected. Indeed google was caching the page for the second part of the function. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sh = ss.getSheetByName('Configuracion');
  //start counting time for the first part
  let dt1 = new Date();
  let vs = sh.getRange(11, 40, 50, 36).getValues()
  let arr1 = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 36; i = i + 4) {
    for (let j = 0; j < vs.length; j++) {
      if (vs[j][i + 1] > 0) {
        arr1.push([vs[j][i], vs[j][i + 1]])
      }
    }
  }
  let dt2 = new Date();
  Logger.log(myTimeDiff(dt1,dt2));

  //start of the second part 
  let dt3 = new Date
  let arr2 = []
  for (let k = 40; k <= 72; k = k + 4) {
    arr2 = arr2.concat(sh.getRange(11, k, 50, 2).getValues())
  }
  let arr3 = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr2[i][1] != '') {
      arr3.push(arr2[i])
    }
  }
  let dt4 = new Date()
  Logger.log(myTimeDiff(dt3,dt4))
  return (arr3)
}

function myTimeDiff(Start, End) {
  if (Start && End) {
    var second = 1000;
    var minute = 60 * second;
    var hour = minute * 60;
    var day = hour * 24;
    var t1 = new Date(Start).valueOf();
    var t2 = new Date(End).valueOf();
    var d = t2 - t1;
    var days = Math.floor(d / day);
    var hours = Math.floor(d % day / hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor(d % day % hour / minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor(d % day % hour % minute / second);
    return 'dd:hh:mm:ss\n' + days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;  
    //return d / day;
    //return hours + minutes/60;
  }
  else {
    return 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}
```

- [Date.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Javascript Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion. I don't need to actually try the new code, as the problem was not counting with the cached page google saves. So for the second part of the function google had already access to the data, therefore the comparison was not fair. The actual difference is around 50ms in favor for the 1st part (after running the functions separately). Thank you.