# Is there a way to ONLY search through cell values that are not hidden by a filter? (Google Sheets Apps Scripts)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm writing a script to filter out all values that do not start with 'PNDXD' or 'PNDCROSS', however I haven't found a way to filter that exact way so I've worked around it by setting any values that are 'PNDCROSS' to 'PNDXD' and then just filter for values starting with 'PNDXD'

In trying to optimize the search for 'PNDCROSS' I've set a filter to first only show 'PNDCROSS' so I can just set all the values that show up to 'PNDXD' and then remove the filter and set a new one to only show values that start with 'PNDXD'.

```
for (let currentRow = locationColumn.getLastRow(); currentRow > 1; currentRow--) {

  //still looks through all 4k rows
  if(SHEET.isRowHiddenByFilter(currentRow)){
    continue;
  }

  var currentCell;

  currentCell = SHEET.getRange(currentRow, locationColumnArg);

  
  currentCell.setValue('PNDXD');
}
```

This snippet comes after the filter that only shows 'PNDCROSS'
This gets the last row with data (since I have to search through all of them), if it passes the if statement - it sets the value to 'PNDXD'.

This however still looks through every cell. Would there be a more efficient way to do this? Perhaps by creating an array from the column but only from cells that aren't hidden? I'm unsure and help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Using filter and looping will still be slow. You need to batch: get all data as batch and set back the modified batch: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57836700/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked two questions: Is there a way to ONLY search through cell values that are not hidden by a filter? Yes (but it is not efficient). Would there be a more efficient way to do this? Yes, keep reading.

If your goal is to optimize the efficiency of your script, your strategy has to change. As others have mentioned, you'll want to switch to batch processing.

The main bottleneck is that the code makes multiple network requests for each row. It's calling `isRowHiddenByFilter`, and/or `setRange`, and `setValue`. The script makes *at minimum* 4 thousand network requests on a single run.

Consider fetching all the data, manipulating the data in memory, and saving it back to the sheet.

For example, get all the rows in one call to `getRange`:

```
// Do this outside the loop
const values = SHEET.getRange(2, 1, getLastRow(), getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

Now `values` is a two-dimensional array that you can manipulate without calling `SpreadsheetApp` methods.

```
[
    ["row 2 cell1", "row 2 cell2", "row 2 cell3", ...],
    ["row 3 cell1", "row 3 cell2", "row 3 cell3", ...],
    ["row 4 cell1", "row 4 cell2", "row 4 cell3", ...],
    ...
]
```

You'll have to completely re-write your `for` loop to handle processing the two-dimensional array.

Consider this two-dimensional array:

```js
const values = [
    ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
    ['fizz', 'buzz', 'bazz']    
]
```

To fetch one of the values in the data structure you have to provide two indices.

```
values[0][0] // foo
values[0][1] // bar
values[0][2] // baz
values[1][0] // fizz
values[1][1] // buzz
values[1][2] // bazz
```

One `for` loop will help with the first index:

```
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    console.log(values[i][?]) // This is an error because we haven't specified the second index properly
}
```

To specify the second index, a second loop comes in handy:

```
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(values[i][j])
        // do something with values[i][j] here like update its value.
        // values[i][j] = "new value"
    }
}
```

After manipulating the data, write `values` back to the sheet.

```
SHEET.getRange(2, 1, getLastRow(), getLastColumn()).setValues(values);
```

That's two API calls instead of 4 thousand. Better.

More reading: [Long processing time likely due to getValue and cell inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289183/long-processing-time-likely-due-to-getvalue-and-cell-inserts/57836700#57836700)

Comment: Thank you for all the insight and guidance. I really appreciate it! I will get dug into this and I'll get back here with how it goes. Thank you again!

Comment: I do have one extra question - the range I'll be looking into is one column - I know how to do that bit - however if I were to need to go through every value in a 2D array how would I go about doing that in a for loop? I'm trying to wrap my head around it but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a basic example of using loops to traverse a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function onlyVisibleRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [hs, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues().filter((r,i) => !sh.isRowHiddenByFilter(i + 1));
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs))
  // put your code down here
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to most coding - could you break down the const [hs, ...vs] line for me?
I'm not 100% certain what it does but if I knew I might be able to use it on other projects as well.

Also by the put your code down here comment, I assume you mean the code I've supplied but I suppose I fail to see how adding the function you've suggested would have any effect on how many rows my code searches through since the searching loop itself has not been modified.

Comment: It's called an array literal assignment. hs is assigned the first line and vs is assigned the rest of the lines.  The assumption is that you have a header on line one and the rest is data

Comment: That is a good assumption. So, the //put your code down here would be my for loop. Then call that onlyVisibleRows() function to do the sorting after the filter is added?
Also I suppose I will do some research on filters in the Apps Scripts documentation.